Adding additional edges in the forest
I have the following graph created by "forest"
\documentclass[tikz,border=5pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{forest}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
\begin{document}    

\begin{forest}
   for tree={draw=black, s sep=0.5cm, l sep=\lvld,
    edge={draw=black,thick,-latex}},
  [{(a)}, label=right:\textcolor{red}{(1,2)}
    [{(b)}, label=left:\textcolor{red}{(5,6)}
        [{(c)}, label=left:\textcolor{red}{(1,2)}
            [{(d)}, label=left:\textcolor{red}{(0,0)}    
                [{(e)}, label=below:\textcolor{red}{(2,1)}]
            ]
        ]        
    ]
    [{(f)}, label=right:\textcolor{red}{(1,1)}
        [{(g)}, label={[xshift=-7pt]above:\textcolor{red}{(1,2)}}]
    [{(i)}, label=right:\textcolor{red}{(1,4)}
            [{(h)}, label=below:\textcolor{red}{(4,1)}]
            [{(j)}, label=below:\textcolor{red}{(5,1)}]
            ]        
        ]    
    ]
]
\end{forest}

\end{document}

Now I need to add additional directed arrows going from (f) to (c), from (c) to (h), from (g) to (d), and from (g) to (j). Is it possible within the current structure, if not how can I proceed?

Where is define \lvld ?

That is going to create criss-crossing  lines and lines which cross labels etc. Is that intentional or are you trying to change the structure, too?

A simple (and a bit rude) solution is naming of nodes and after tree draw additional edges. An example, where I draw just one additional arrow (other I left to you) is:

\documentclass[tikz,border=5pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{forest}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
\tikzset{every label/.style = {font=\footnotesize,  text=red,
                               inner sep=1pt }}

\begin{document}    

\begin{forest}
    for tree = {
        draw, 
        s sep=5mm, 
        l sep=5mm,
        edge={thick,-Latex},
                }
[{(a)}, label=right:{(1,2)}
    [{(b)}, label=left:{(5,6)}
        [{(c)}, label=left:{(1,2)}, name=c
            [{(d)}, label=left:{(0,0)}    
                [{(e)}, label=below:{(2,1)}]
            ]
    ]        
]
    [{(f)}, label=right:{(1,1)}, name=f
        [{(g)}, label={[xshift=-7pt]above:{(1,2)}}]
    [{(i)}, label=right:{(1,4)}
            [{(h)}, label=below:{(4,1)}]
            [{(j)}, label=below:{(5,1)}]
            ]        
        ]    
    ]
]
\draw[-Latex, semitransparent] (f) -- (c);
\end{forest}
\end{document}


I would need the same style of the edge (f,c) if possible.

@Vika, this should not be a problem, rather good opportunity to learn something about tikz and than do this yourself . Just remove option semitransparent from draw command (if I correctly understood your comment).

I removed that already, but the arrow style (size) is different (unless there is something wrong with my vision).

Ok. I think I was able to fix that as well. Thank you!

@Vika, now I see, that the thickness of line is not the same as it as edges in tree. For this the options for \draw should be the same as is defined for edges in for tree options: thick,-Latex. I'm glad that you succeed to managed this yourself!
